# ExcelDataReader 3.4 - System.IO.FileLoadException

Tags: exceldatareader, fileloadexception, system.io.compression

I'm using ExcelDataReader 3.4 and it work fine on my developer PC, but when used on production PC, I've got this error

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Compression, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT : 0x80131040)

In my project I have `System.IO.Compression` copied local.
I'm using .NET 4.5, Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. In the App.Config of my WPF application there was those line

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Compression" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

I changed the version for 4.0.0.0 and now its working.